# Finding Friction and Coefficient of Friction Force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction

A $65\,\mathrm{kg}$ object slides down a $30^\circ$ slope at a constant speed. Air resistance is negligible. Find the coefficient of friction and force of friction.

The normal force equals $F_\text{normal} = 637   \ \mathrm{N} (=Gravity * Mass) \cos{(30^\circ)}$. But this does not yet give the coefficient of friction.

Now to the parallel force on the object 
$F_\text{parallel} = 637\,\mathrm{N} \cdot \sin{(30^\circ)} = 318.5\,\mathrm N$, which friction must overcome. Then, I divided that by the $F_\text{normal}$ and got $0.577$ as the coefficient.

Did I do it right? If I didn't, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You might spend a little time formatting (with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) and clarifying (where did "637" come from?) your problem; you're more likely to get quality answers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an object to move in a constant velocity the zero acceleration then the Forces should be zero.
The $$\mu=\frac{65*g*\sin 30}{65*g*\cos30}=0.57735$$
Your answer is perfectly true. $$\mu<1$$
if your question is why does the object still move even when force is zero. Example is Terminal Velocity.in air.

The reason the object comes down is that there is a constant g vector is applied by gravity.
It has potential energy stored which it releases to kinetic energy and wants to come to zero state.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta$ is the slope angle. The normal force is $F_{N} = mg\cos{\theta}$, which you have calculated. Now there are three important points to consider.

1. The object is in constant speed, so $F_{net} = 0$.
2. There are three forces acting on the object $F_{friction}, ~F_{gravity} ~and ~ -F_{normal }$ whose net sum is zero to justify **(1).**
3. $F_{friction}$ by definition is $\mu F_{normal}$ where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction.

Using the above clues, you can find the answer.

Comment: Good answer, but I know everything you just said. I wanted to make sure I was doing this the correct way. Without the coefficient of friction, I supposed I had to calculate the frictional force necessary for no acceleration. Therefore, I thought to myself, what if there was no friction. Then MG*Sin theta would equal the parallel force, which must surely be equal to frictional force. So that is what I did. Did I do it right?

Comment: The 3rd point clarifies that. Wait, are you expecting us to evaluate your answer like in a test? If you understand the 3 points correctly, I think there is no need for further explanation or *reinforcement*.